# Is there any way to use python OpenSSL module to convert certificate from pkcs7 format to pem format

Tags: python, openssl, pyopenssl

Is there any way to use python OpenSSL module to convert a certificate from pkcs7 format to pem format?

I saw this link: [Is there any OpenSSL function to convert PKCS7 file to PEM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023046/is-there-any-openssl-function-to-convert-pkcs7-file-to-pem) with a C++ answer, but is there any way in python?

I have a pkcs7 format certificate needed to be converted to pem format in python code. I searched on the Internet. It seems the most common way to do this is by using OpenSSL command line like below:

```
OpenSSL pkcs7 -in intermediate.cert.p7b -text -out test.pem -print_certs
```

I read the python OpenSSL module; it only provides some methods for checking pkcs7 format, but not something like get_certificate.

I not quite familiar with the algorithm of converting pkcs7 to pem, is there any reference for this?

Before I use the python os.system module to call the Linux OpenSSL command directly (I do not quite want to do it in this way). I am trying to look for some help from StackOverflow; please help, thanks in advance.